# 'I have got transferred' or 'I have got transfer'?

Tags: grammaticality

> I have got transferred to Bangalore.

or

> I have got transfer to Bangalore.

Do these sentence mean the same thing? Which sentence is correct?

Comment: In a conversational register, the first sentence would usually be 'I've been transferred to Bangalore' in British English. The second is non-standard; 'I've got a transfer to Bangalore' is standard. In most situations, there would be no difference in meaning, though the second sentence can imply that you've been trying hard to get the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Edwin, above.  You would either say "I was transferred to Bangalore" if it has already happened and you are now in Bangalore, or "I have been transferred to Bangalore", which means that you have received the news of the transfer but have not left yet.  Also, a transfer can be a noun.  It can mean a new position that you received from your work or a portion of a ticket from an airline company.  If it is a noun, you can say "I got a transfer to Bangalore" or more formally "I received a transfer to Bangalore".  These are American English phrases.

Comment: +1..If you've been moved from one job site to another — you have been transferred.

Answer (score -1):

These sentences are different in meaning. The first one means that you've been given a lift to Bangalore, you're standing there. The second one lacks the `a` article in front of `transfer`. Having that fix in place, it would mean that you only have a transfer arranged (going to be transferred), and haven't yet been transferred.

Comment: I think the most common reading of the first sentence would be "I was moved to Bangalore for my job".